# Sort an array of object on month basis

Tags: javascript

I am working with the dashboard and I have a chart in which I have to show count against month label. I have an array of objects with count and month Key. I want to sort this array of objects in Ascending order with month key value. I tried below code works fine in chrome but array does on get sorted in Firefox.

```
var xAxis =  [
{count: 0, month: "Jan 2019"},
{count: 7, month: "Dec 2019"},
{count: 0, month: "Feb 2019"},
{count: 0, month: "Jul 2019"}
] 

 xAxis.sort(function(a, b) {
  var c = new Date(a.month);
  console.log("TCL: CountByUserGraph -> makeApiCall -> c", c)
  // Chrome showing  ==> Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 
  //firefox showing  ==> Invalid Date
  var d = new Date(b.month);
  return c - d;
});
```

Comment: [`Date.parse()` / `new Date(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse): _"It is not recommended to use `Date.parse` as until ES5, parsing of strings was entirely implementation dependent. There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many different formats are to be accommodated)"_

Comment: date-fns is a great date library and does contain a very useful parse method, just to add to Andreas comment :)

Comment: variables c & d are going to be same as you are creating date out of a.month in both the cases

Answer (score 3):

The following implementation compares the year as well as month -

```js
const sortByMonth = arr => {
  const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  const getIndexOfMonth = month => months.indexOf(month)
  return [ ...arr ].sort((left, right) => {
    const [ leftMonth, leftYear ] = left.month.split(' ')
    const [ rightMonth, rightYear ] = right.month.split(' ')
    if (leftYear !== rightYear) {
      return parseInt(leftYear) - parseInt(rightYear)
    }
    return getIndexOfMonth(leftMonth) - getIndexOfMonth(rightMonth)
  })
}

var xAxis =  [
  {count: 0, month: "Jan 2019"},
  {count: 7, month: "Dec 2019"},
  {count: 0, month: "Dec 2017"},
  {count: 0, month: "Jun 2018"},
  {count: 0, month: "Feb 2019"},
  {count: 0, month: "Jul 2019"},
];

console.log(sortByMonth(xAxis))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array which contains all of the short names of the months. Then, splitting the string in your input to get the short name of the month, and comparing it with the items in the array.

```js
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 
              'May', 'June', 'Jul', 'Aug', 
              'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

var xAxis =  [
{count: 0, month: "Jan 2019"},
{count: 7, month: "Dec 2019"},
{count: 0, month: "Feb 2019"},
{count: 0, month: "Jul 2019"}
];

var output = xAxis.sort(function (a, b) { 
    return months.indexOf(a.month.substr(0, 3)) - months.indexOf(b.month.substr(0, 3)) 
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's `Date` implementation cannot parse strings in `MMM YYYY` format like the ones in your example. Consider using a different format. If you must use this format, consider using a library that allows you to parse these dates across browsers like [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo. Let me show you:

```js
var xAxis =  [
{count: 0, month: "Jan 2019"},
{count: 7, month: "Dec 2019"},
{count: 0, month: "Feb 2019"},
{count: 0, month: "Jul 2019"}
] 

 xAxis.sort(function(a, b) {
  var c = new Date(a.month);
  // console.log("TCL: CountByUserGraph -> makeApiCall -> c", c)
  // Chrome showing  ==> Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 
  //firefox showing  ==> Invalid Date
  var d = new Date(b.month);
  return c - d;
});

console.log(xAxis);
```

the typo line was `var d = ...`. You were setting both dates to the `a` value

[edit] please note: the code I posted above works in Chrome, but a user Alexander posted below that the same code will not work in every browser.